# When merging two branches in git, how to accept entire subfolders from ours/theirs?

Tags: git, git-merge

I have two branches of code, branch a and branch b.  When merging, I need to look through many subdirectories and on a case by case basis, take entire subdirectories from either branch.  So for example,

subdirA -> I want 'ours'

sunbirB -> I want 'theirs'

and so forth.  What is the easiest way of doing this?  I want to make sure that when I choose 'theirs' (or ours) I get that entire folder exactly as it exists in 'ours' or 'theirs', ie, I don't want a non-conflicted file to show up from either branch.

Is it as simple as attempting the merge, seeing the conflicts, removing the subdir with conflicts, doing a git checkout of the subdir with --ours or --theirs and then adding it back to the stage?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can indeed do

```
git checkout <our-branch>
git merge --no-commit <their-branch>

git checkout --ours -- path/to/subfolder1
git checkout --theirs -- path/to/subfolder2

git add path/to/subfolder1 path/to/subfolder2
git commit -m "Explanations of what was made here"
```

Let's add that if at some point (before you commit, of course) you need to see how the directory looked when the conflict occured, with markers and such, you can use the `-m` flag for that

```
git checkout -m -- path/to/subfolder1
```